# p5.js to processing vector array

Tags: processing, p5.js

I'm sure it's simple but I don't know how to do it.
How do I translate vector array as argument from processing to p5.js in the fisrt line of my code.
many thanks David

```
int inPolyCheck(PVector v, PVector [] p) {
  float a = 0;
  for (int i =0; i<p.length-1; ++i) {
    PVector v1 = p[i].get();
    PVector v2 = p[i+1].get();
    a += vAtan2cent180(v, v1, v2);
  }
  PVector v1 = p[p.length-1].get();
  PVector v2 = p[0].get();
  a += vAtan2cent180(v, v1, v2);
  if (abs(abs(a) - TWO_PI) < 0.01) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

float vAtan2cent180(PVector cent, PVector v2, PVector v1) {
  PVector vA = v1.get();
  PVector vB = v2.get();
  vA.sub(cent);
  vB.sub(cent);
  vB.mult(-1);
  float ang = atan2(vB.x, vB.y) - atan2(vA.x, vA.y);
  if (ang < 0) ang = TWO_PI + ang;
  ang-=PI;
  return ang;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried googling "JavaScript arrays"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is **dynamically** typed, unlike Java which is **statically** typed.

#### What does that mean for you?

It means you don't have to worry about declaring data types of variables(in this case, the arguments). The datatype of a variable is automatically configured according to the type of data stored in it. I think that is enough info to let you figure out what you need to do, if not then I would suggest you learn Javascript before learning how to replicate Processing code in Javascript.

Comment: thanks I'm new and I thought I still have to declare arrays